# QTableView cannot hide column

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

Well, here is the problem:

1. I construct a `QTableView` and use the `setModel(myModel)` method which bind the model `myModel` to `myTableView`;
2. At first, there's no data in `myModel`, I use the `hideColumn(0)` to do the job, and it works well, while after I load data to `myModel`, the column that I've hidden just shows up.

Would anyone tell me **how to hold the hidden state of a column** when the model changes?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

OK, here is the code.

```
void ModelView::createModelAndView()
{

    _TableModel = new TableModel(this);

    _Table = new QTableView(this);

    _Table->setModel(_TableModel);

    _Table->hideColumn(0);      
    _Table->hideColumn(10);     
}
```

Now the `_TableModel` has no data.

Then follows this:

```
_TableModel->loadData();
```

The `loadData()` method is used to get data and push data to the model. Right after this step the view(i.e. `_Table`) changes.

Comment: Do you constantly change the model?

Comment: Nope, what makes the big difference is just whether there is data(i.e. item) in it.

Comment: Well I was asking because the hidden columns should stick when the model data changes...but probably not when you are changing the model to another one.

Comment: I do not change the model, there is just one model, and the model cannot fetch all the items during the initialization, but later with a method to load data into it. So the model doesn't change, neither should the view.

Comment: Right, but once you set the column hidden after it pulls data the first time, it should stay that way in the view. The problem is that the view is never given a dimension of the model until it gets some data. What type of model are you using? If its a QStandardItemModel, do you init it with a row/col value?

Comment: So...what i should do is to hide the column after the data is loaded?

Comment: Yes, i use QStandardItemModel and i init it with just a column value because the rowCount is uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
connect(dataModel, SIGNAL(modelReset()), SLOT(modelReset()));
```

in the `modelReset()` slot:

```
void SomeClass::modelReset()
{
  tableView->hideColumn(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you set a data model, then tweak its GUI representation:

```
tableView->setModel(dataModel);
tableView->hideColumn(0);
```

Comment: Yeah..But you said above is exactly what i did.. The point is that at first there's **NO** data in it and then i add data into it, and the hidden column just showed up.

Comment: You must be changing a data model, not data in it. Show us your code.

Comment: When you pull data into your model, the model most likey resets. This could mean anything, including the addition/deletion of columns. The GUI resets along with the model.